# Changing the table query in Access

Tags: ms-access

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcueI.jpg
In this picture I'm showing how the two queries are showing up as different names, I know that I can
rename the custom query tab, but when I open it up it holds the same wrong name, I know in SQL in the from statement I could write AS "new name" but it doesn't seem to work here, any solutions?

Thanks

Comment: No idea why the query window shows different name from name in Navigation Pane. I cannot replicate issue. Using "AS NewName" in SQL has nothing to do with what is displayed.

Comment: ya, its really weird, it doesnt look like its in the code or design view either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using custom groups, and if you change its navigation name, it would change only the shortcut name, not the query name.
To do so, change the navigation pan view from "custom" to "object Type" then change the original query name.

I stopped using custom view because of such conflict

Comment: Awesome! And it looks like I can change the name in object type and switch back to custom which is good. How do you keep it organized when it's just object type, as with the custom we can create groups and dropdowns?

Comment: You are right but I'm trying to manage with objects names